# Проверить наличие определенного GET через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Есть файл в корне сайта (назовем file.php)
Необходимо через htaccess обрубить к нему доступ, если в обращении (ссылке) отсутствует определенный GET параметр.
Например:

- domen/file.php - нет доступа
- domen/file.php?test=1 - нет
  доступа
- domen/file.php?trueparam=abc&secondparam=123 - есть
  доступ (тут нужный параметр)

можно ли сделать как-то через exceptlimit или правила редиректа с флагом F (или другим)?

Comment: дак и проверьте в `RewriteCond` значение `%{QUERY_STRING}` на `\bparam=`

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам проверять через .htaccess, делайте просто проверку на get-параметр в php, если его нет, то выдавайте ошибку или редирект.

Comment: 1. Это комментарий, а не ответ: пожалуйста, пишите комментарии под вопросом 2. Если вам любопытно зачем (и не просто "так надо"), то ответ может быть "так значительно экономит ресурсы сервера - не надо подымать тяжеловесный поток PHP, достаточно на самом веб-сервере отбить".